# How to show only visible GMSPolyline on google map? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, overlays

I have many GMSPolyline on my app end it laggy.
I want to show only visible GMSPolyline.
So if i want to see New York, no need to load all world to google map memory

Comment: you can zoom to particular coordinate!

Comment: Yes, but when i zoom the polygons still in memory. I need to remove from google map GMSPolyline outside of screen.

I mean when i have 1 million polylines over the world no need to load all this polylines when i want to see only New York.